# Lightining component Canvas width based on screen width?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura

how can i set the width of a canvas in a lightning component to be 100% of the screen width? If i apply the value "100%" it doesn't work.

```
            <canvas aura:id="canvas" width="300" height="250" style="border:1px solid #ddd;background: white;">
</canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use a container element with relative/absolute positioning:

```
<div style="position: relative; height: 100px; width: 100%">
    <canvas style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%">
    </canvas>
</div>
```

Or you can specify 100vw:

```
<canvas style="width: 100vw; height: 50vh">
</canvas>
```

Where 100 units of vw is 100% of the viewport width, and 100 units of vh is 100% of the viewport height (here, demonstrated to be set to 50%).

Comment: Ok so if i set the style="width: 100vw; height: 50vh" it works, but it messes up with the component behavior ( i have the canvas that works as a signature pad ).

if i set the canvas as this : 

<canvas aura:id="canvas" width="100vw" height="50vh" style="border:1px solid #ddd;background: white;"></canvas>
        </div>
it creates it with dimensions 0x0

Comment: @Brian23Gt I wrote up a demo for you to look at. You need to reset the size of the canvas to match the expected size. [demo](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/vED8XJwfsyMfn2IFlCld/src/app.css?p=stories).

Comment: Thanks a lot mate!